# Erasing type parameter

Tags: ocaml, phantom-types

I have a module Socket using phantom types to enforce some simple access control:

```
module Socket : sig
  type 'a t

  val ro : string -> [ `Read ] t
  val rw : string -> [ `Read | `Write ] t
end
```

I want to wrap a Socket.t in a Container.t record, but is there some way **not** to propagate the phantom type parameter also into
Container.t?

```
module Container : sig
  type 'a t =
  {     
  owner: string;
  socket: 'a Socket.t;
  }     
end
```

Comment: What is wrong with defining the `socket` field to have type `[ 'Read | 'Write ] Socket.t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you may use existential types to forget about some type parameter: instead of the type `'a foo`, you use `exists_foo` that contains a value of type `'a foo`, for some `'a` you don't know about. There are several ways to build existential types in OCaml (polymorphic records or first-class modules).

In the case of a phantom type, you can provide a way, through your interface, to convert any socket into an "untyped socket" that has forgotten about its previous capabilities.

```
type untyped

module Socket : sig
  type 'a t

  val ro : string -> [ `Read ] t
  val rw : string -> [ `Read | `Write ] t
  val untyped : 'a t -> untyped t
end = struct
  type 'a t = string
  let ro s = s
  let rw s = s
  let untyped s = s
end

type t = { owner : string; socket : untyped Socket.t }

let test = {
  owner = "foo";
  socket = Socket.(untyped (ro "bar"))
}
```

Of course, you have to choose what is possible for an untyped socket, for which you don't know anymore how it was opened. Maybe it's not what you had in mind?

You can also keep the socket in a sum type, to preserve the knowledge of its capabilities:

```
module Socket : sig
  type 'a t
  val ro : string -> [ `Read ] t
  val rw : string -> [ `Read | `Write ] t

  val read : [> `Read ] t -> unit
  val write : [> `Write ] t -> unit
end = struct
  type 'a t = string
  let ro s = s
  let rw s = s
  let read _ = ()
  let write _ = ()
end

type some_socket =
  | Ro of [ `Read ] Socket.t
  | Rw of [ `Read | `Write ] Socket.t

type t = { owner : string; socket : some_socket }

let test = {
  owner = "foo";
  socket = Ro (Socket.ro "bar")
}

let write container = match container.socket with
  | Ro _ -> failwith "write not allowed"
  | Rw s -> Socket.write s
```

Finally, there is another way to implement the first solution: instead of using a top `untyped` type, you may allow subtyping of values at type Socket. For this you need to specify, in your interface, the variance of the `Socket.t` type: is it invariant (`'a t`), covariant (`+'a t`) or contravariant (`-'a t`)?

If your mental model is that a phantom variant type with more cases is "more capable", then subtyping should go from a variant with some cases to a variant with less cases, which is a smaller type: to have `a t` ≤ `b t` one should have `a` ≥ `b` (`a` has more cases): `t` should be contravariant.

```
module Socket : sig
  type -'a t
  val ro : string -> [ `Read ] t
  val rw : string -> [ `Read | `Write ] t

  val read : [> `Read ] t -> unit
  val write : [> `Write ] t -> unit
end = struct
  type 'a t = string
  let ro s = s
  let rw s = s
  let read _ = ()
  let write _ = ()
end

type t = { owner : string; socket : [ `Read ] Socket.t }

let test = {
  owner = "foo";
  socket = (Socket.rw "bar" :> [ `Read ] Socket.t)
}
```

Notice the explicit cast `` (socket :> [ `Read ]) Socket.t `` to a smaller socket type.

Comment: Interestingly you state polymorphic records and first-class modules as the two possible techniques but use neither in your answer.

Comment: Polymorphic records and first-class modules could be used to build an existential type -- with newer versions of OCaml, GADTs are also available and are more convenient than those. Existentials are used, informally, to build a type `exists_foo` that is "larger" than all the `'a foo`. You don't need them if you know the domain the domain of all possible `'a` types in your precise case, and this domain has a largest element `top`; in this case, just write an explicit conversion from `'a foo` to `top foo` are you're done.